# Error processing purchase [BM-CPH-08]

Tags: android

I have done correct setup for in app billing api in my application but
     when i am going to purchase i am getting " Error processing purchase [BM-CPH-08] "
     So please help me, how to resolve this problem .

Thank you to all ..

Comment: add your error log....

Answer (score 1):

I have face same problem. In my case I have device which linked to google apps account (gmail for custom domain). Just remove all accounts and sign in again.

Related issue [Error processing purchase BM-CPH-08](http://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/issues/detail?id=162) in IAP helper repo